# Must $S$ be a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $S\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}$ invertible matrix, and let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ prove or give a counterexample that :

> $$S \textrm { is unitary }\iff\frac{\|Sx-Sy\|}{\|Sx\|}=\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|} $$

Comment: One is expected to include the text in the post not link to an image. Also see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: If **S** is unitary then it preserves the 2-norm. This automatically makes the equation true. But I don't know how to get from the equation back to unitary.

Comment: Thank you for helping out, I had to rephrase the question because the mathematical need considers unitary matrices as relevant as matrices that would become unitary by scaling. I posted a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Of course the direction $\Longrightarrow$ is trivially true.

In the converse direction, consider matrices of the form $\lambda\cdot \text{Id}$, for some constant $|\lambda| \neq 1$.

Comment: Yes, $\text{Id}$ is the identity matrix. The equation indeed holds true, as you noticed, but $\lambda \text{Id}$ is **not** unitary.

Comment: @Tony it's the *converse*. $\lambda \cdot$ **Id** fails to be unitary, even though it satisfies the equality.

Comment: You are right, I did not ask the question I intended

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no for this you can take $S_\alpha=\alpha T$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ an $T$ is any unitary matrix then $S_\alpha$ is unitary if and only if $|\alpha|=1$ but :
$$
\frac{\|Sx-Sy\|}{\|Sx\|}=\frac{|\alpha|\|T(x-y)\|}{|\alpha|\|Tx\|}=\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|}
$$

Comment: You are right, I did not ask the question I intended.