# Must $aS$ be a unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $S\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}$ invertible matrix, and let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ prove or give a counterexample that :
There exists $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

> $$aS \textrm { is unitary }\iff\frac{\|Sx-Sy\|}{\|Sx\|}=\frac{\|x-y\|}{\|x\|} $$

Meaninng, the equation holds iff $S$ is proportional to some unitary matrix.

Comment: Continuation from [this variant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904502/must-s-be-a-unitary-matrix) It is helpful to link back for context.

Answer (score 1):

the answer is yes in this case in fact : the fact that $S$ is invertible is equivalent to say that $S$ is injective, so we put $z=x-y$ we have so :
$$
\frac{\|Sz\|}{\|Sx\|}=\frac{\|z\|}{\|x\|}
$$
this is equivalent (using injectivity) to :
$$
\frac{\|Sz\|}{\|z\|}=\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|} \qquad \forall x,z\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
\|Sx\|=\|Sy\|= \alpha  \qquad \forall x,y\in S_n \qquad (*)
$$
where $S_n=\{ x; \|x\|=1\} $ mean the unit sphere of  $\mathbb{R}^n$
so our matrix transform the unit sphere to a sphere of radius $\alpha$.

we will use [the polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Matrix_polar_decomposition) of $S$ so $S=U|S|$ where $U$ is unitary and $|S|$ is a  positive-semidefinite Hermitian matrix. so $(*)$ mean :
\begin{eqnarray}
\|Sx\|&=&\|Sy\|\\
\|U|S|x\|&=&\|U|S|y\|\\
\||S|x\|&=&\||S|y\|
\end{eqnarray}
we calculate the eigenvalues of $|S|$, so let $a\geq 0$ a eigenvalue of $|S|$ (it will be positive because |S| is positive semidefinite) and let $x\in S_n$ a eigenvector of S then :
$$
Sx=ax \implies  \alpha=\|Sx\|=a\|x\|=a
$$
so 
$$\sigma(S)=\{\alpha\}$$
and using spectral theorem we have :
$$
|S|=WDW^*
$$
where $W$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal, since $\sigma(S)=\{\alpha\}$, $D=\alpha I_n$ so $|S|=\alpha W I_n W^*=\alpha I_n$
finally:
$$
S=U|S|=U\alpha I_n=\alpha U
$$ 
where $U$ is unitary.

Comment: Looks perfect, all is clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.  The $\implies$ direction is clear, so here's a quick proof of the converse.

First, deduce from the equation that for all $x,y \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
\frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|Sy\|}{\|y\|}
$$
which is to say that there is a constant $a \geq 0$ such that $\|Sx\|/\|x\| = a$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$.

We note that the singular values of $S$ satisfy
$$
\sigma_{\max}(S) = \max_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}, \qquad
\sigma_{\min}(S) = \min_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Sx\|}{\|x\|}
$$
we can conclude that both of these singular values are equal to $a$.  It follows that in the singular value decomposition $S = U \Sigma V^T$, we have $\Sigma = sI$.  It follows that $S = s(UV^T)$, from which we conclude that $S$ is a multiple of a unitary matrix, as desired.